# When accessing characters of strings to be pushed into an vector of unions, strings in vector get messed up

Tags: c++, string, vector, unions

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (simple example to show the problem):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

enum Type {oInt, oFloat, oString, oArray};

struct Object; // fwd decl for union
union ObjectNative {
    int oInt;
    float oFloat;
    const char* oString;
    vector<Object>* oArray;
};
struct Object {
    Type type;
    ObjectNative obj;
};

vector<Object> exec(vector<string> tokens, vector<Object> stack);
void printStack(vector<Object> stack);

int main() {
    vector<string> tokens{"test", "another test", "even more test", "test test", "test test test", "lotsa test"};
    vector<Object> stack;
    stack = exec(tokens, stack);
    printStack(stack);

    return 0;
}

vector<Object> exec(vector<string> tokens, vector<Object> stack) {
    for (string s : tokens) {
        ObjectNative nObj;

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THIS LINE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        s[0];

        nObj.oString = s.c_str();
        Object obj = Object{oString, nObj};
        stack.push_back(obj);

        // debugging lines
        printStack(stack);
        cout << "-------" << endl;
    }
    return stack;
}

void printStack(vector<Object> stack) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i ++) {
        Object o = stack[i];
        cout << o.obj.oString;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Notice the line I marked in the `exec` function:

```
s[0];
```

I'm just accessing the first character in the string; I'm not even doing anything with it! However, if I comment out that line, I get the correct output:

```
test
-------
test
another test
-------
(etc....)
-------
test
another test
even more test
test test
test test test
lotsa test
```

But with that line, I... uh, I'm not sure what's happening. This is the output:

```
test
-------
ä7R
another test
-------
ä7R
even more test
even more test
-------
test test
ä7R
ä7R
test test
-------
test test
test test test
test test test
test test
test test test
-------
lotsa test
ä7R
ä7R
lotsa test
ä7R
lotsa test
-------
lotsa test
ä7R
ä7R
lotsa test
ä7R
lotsa test
```

It seems like there's nothing wrong with the code, but clearly I'm doing something very wrong. Why is the vector being corrupted like this, and how on earth is it being caused by doing nothing with the first character of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime of the `const char *` returned by `string::c_str()` is limited.  If you're trying to keep those strings, you need to copy them into storage dedicated for the purpose.

The string `s` gets replaced by a new string from `tokens` on each iteration.  When the `for` loop assigns a new string to `s` on the next iteration, it is allowed to invalidate the `c_str()` from the previous iteration as a result.

The fact that it worked at all is probably a lucky fluke of the implementation:  Under the hood, `s` may have borrowed the storage for the string from the entry in `tokens`.  The call to `operator[]`, however, was probably causing it to make its own, private copy of the string.  That would explain the difference in behavior for `c_str()`.

To save copy in dedicated storage, you need to allocate space for it and copy the string into it.  Code like the following would suffice:

```
nObj.oString = new char[s.size() + 1];  // allocate the space
std::strcpy( nObj.oString, s.c_str() ); // copy in the string
```

Now, techically, this won't copy in the entire `string` if it contains ASCII NULs.  Your original code didn't care about those and my suggestion above doesn't change that.  :-)  You can find `std::strcpy()` in `<cstring>`.

Note that because you've allocated your own storage with `new[]`, you'll have to remember to `delete[]` it later when you're done with it, otherwise you will have a memory leak.  And make sure you use `delete[]`, not `delete` or `free()`.

Comment: okay, so how would I do this? sorry, I'm new to C++. and why is accessing the first character affecting the output?

Comment: @Doorknob : I'm not 100% certain why it might invalidate the `c_str()`, actually.  According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str , the `c_str()` would only be invalidated by passing a non-const reference to the string to a library function, or calling a non-const member on the string (excluding `[]` and some others).

Comment: @Doorknob : As far as allocating storage and copying it out, you can do `char *tmp = new char[s.size() + 1];  std::strcpy(tmp, s.c_str())`, and assign `tmp` to `nObj.oString`.  Just remember to `delete[]` the string later when you're done with it.

Comment: @Doorknob : Oh, wait, I know why the strings are becoming invalid.  They should only be valid for the one iteration, because the `for` loop is assigning each string from `tokens` to `s` in sequence.  The fact that it ever worked at all is a lucky coincidence.  It was probably borrowing the storage in the string in `tokens` without `s[0]`, but once you made a call to `operator[]`, it had to stop borrowing the storage and make its own local copy.

Comment: alright, thanks, I shall try that. If you edit that into your answer and it works I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: umm... it's telling me `'strcpy' is not a member of 'std'`. I tried removing `std::` and it says `'strcpy' was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: Never mind, I had to `#include <string.h>`. It worked! Thank you! Please edit that stuff into your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @Doorknob : Actually `cstring` would be preferred to `string.h`, but either will ultimately give you access to `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is coming from your `exec`:

```
for (string s : tokens)
{
    ObjectNative nObj;

    nObj.oString = s.c_str();
```

Sematically, your `tokens` vector is a copy. Furthermore, `for (string s : tokens)` the `s` is *also* a temporary copy in the loop. When the loop exits `s` will no longer exist. So when you do something like:

```
nObj.oString = s.c_str();
```

Bam! You now have a dangling `const char *`. Now your program has undefined behavior because afterwards you try to print that stack out in `main`.  The fact that `s[0];` causes any behavioral difference at all is irrelavant at this point.

What I would do to fix this, depending on what you're trying to do, is the following:

- Change prototype to `void exec(const vector<string> &tokens, vector<Object> &stack);`
- Modify `s` into a reference. eg. `for (const string &s : tokens)`. This should be ok as long as `tokens` does not outlive `stack`.

Comment: Any modifications to the strings in `tokens` would cause a problem.  If this is a parser, that vector probably gets recycled...

Comment: @joe True. IMO, I think the op should avoid using raw `const char *`. The type representing `Object` needs to be better encapsulated.

Comment: Agreed.  If it were me, I'd just have a `std::string` there, and I might consider polymorphism over a `union`.